# How to Make Language Specific Url in Asp.Net Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, url-routing, westwind-globalization

I used westwind globalization library http://west-wind.com/westwind.globalization/ on my project to implement multiple languages. Everything is working fine. 
Only one problem is that I get culture reference variable at the end of url as http://localhost:18106/LangTest?LocaleId=en.

I want culture reference variable in between domain and page name like http://localhost:18106/en/LangTest.

Acutally I want to do like Microsoft web site http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **IRouteHandler** and you need to create custom routes.

By default, Web Forms use file system request handling. For example the **MyWebsite/contact.aspx** request searches for the **contact.aspx** file located under the root menu. 
**MyWebsite/superheroes/superheroes.aspx** should look for the **superheroes.aspx** file located inside the superheroes file under the root menu.

Using the **global.asax** file you may add our own handling. 
All you need is to call a method, having a **RouteCollection** parameter, from within the **Application_Start** method. 
So you need to create a method called **RegisterRoutes** and place it within a new file called **MyRouteConfig.cs**

Here is example:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Compilation;


public static class MyRouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();     
        routes.MapPageRoute("superheroes", "superhero/{SuperheroName}", "~/superheroes.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("languageSuperheroes", "{language}/superhero/{SuperheroName}", "~/superheroes.aspx");     
        routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{language}/{*page}", new LanguageRouteHandler()));
  } 

   public class LanguageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
   {
       public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
       {
           string page = CheckForNullValue(requestContext.RouteData.Values["page"]);
           string virtualPath = "~/" + page;

           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(page))
           {
               string language= CheckForNullValue(requestContext.RouteData.Values["language"]);
               string newPage = "/home";

               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
                   newPage = "/" + language + newPage;
               HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(newPage, false);
               HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
               HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

              //Otherwise, route to home
              //page = "home";
           }

          if (!virtualPath.Contains(".aspx"))
                virtualPath += ".aspx";

           try
           {
               return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler;
           }
           catch
           {
               return null;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Please have a look to this article: 
http://dotnethints.com/blogs/localization-using-routing-system-on-a-web-forms-project-

Comment: I think this is the best solution for language specific custom routing in asp.net project. thank you very much.